# Stripe invoice.created webhook

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

Stripe suggests adding invoice items in the invoice.created webhook that happens approximately an hour before a subscription is charged. My concern is what happens if the site is down (or there's an error in the webhook). Stripe will charge the invoice without the items I wanted to add to that? This will result in big trouble if it happens for a substantial number of subscriptions. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be described in the docs.

> If your webhooks do not all respond successfully, Stripe will continue retrying the webhooks every hour and will not attempt to pay the invoice. After 3 days, Stripe will attempt to pay the invoice regardless of whether or not your webhooks have succeeded.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.created

3 days should be enough to react to an issue with webhooks, and there's also charge webhook where I can check the amount.